# PowerShell combine strings from x rows into 1 row separated by a comma

Tags: string, powershell, replace

I have the following table (names are one column and colors are another column):

1. Bob      green
2. Bob      red
3. Frank    blue
4. Frank    yellow

that I need to be like this:

1. Bob     green, red
2. Frank   blue, yellow

I've attempted to use group-object in PowerShell but it just gives me the fields in an array. Essentially, I need to grab reach element in the second column (grouped by column 1) and add them as one row with a delimiter.

There's got to be a simple way of doing this that I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a hash table:

```
$table = @(
[PSCustomObject]@{Name='Bob';Color='Green'}
[PSCustomObject]@{Name='Bob';Color='Red'}
[PSCustomObject]@{Name='Frank';Color='Blue'}
[PSCustomObject]@{Name='Frank';Color='Yellow'}
)

$ht = @{}

$Table | 
 foreach { $ht[$_.Name] += @($_.Color) }

 $ht.GetEnumerator() |
  foreach {'{0} {1}' -f $_.Name,($_.Value -join ',') }

Bob Green,Red
Frank Blue,Yellow
```

Comment: This is great. How do I go about this if I need to leverage Import-Csv and read each row?

Comment: Just change to $table = import-csv c:\somedir\somefile.csv . You'll need to change the "Name" and "Color" references to match whatever the actual column headings are in the csv file. You can also do the Import-CSV and pipe that directly into the first foreach, in place of $Table.

Answer (score 1):

I'll go with Group-Object. Borrowing mjolinor's table here, this is the code I have that produces the same results:

```
$table = @(
[PSCustomObject]@{Name='Bob';Color='Green'}
[PSCustomObject]@{Name='Bob';Color='Red'}
[PSCustomObject]@{Name='Frank';Color='Blue'}
[PSCustomObject]@{Name='Frank';Color='Yellow'}
)

$Table | Group Name | ForEach{$_.Name + " " + ($_.Group.Color -join ",")}
```